# CSS property duplication issue

Tags: css

Good Day,

I have an external style sheet that has the following entry:

```
#data-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and it works fine in IE and Firefox but not Chrome.  (I don't have to worry about Safari).

I found out that I can use:  @media only screen to fix it so it works on Chrome (and Safari), so I have another entry like:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    #data-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding-bottom: 14px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;        
    }
}
```

Now it works on Chrome and so far so good.  My concern is that the only attribute I'm interested in is the padding-bottom and it doesn't feel right that I have to use all the other properties for #data-container under @media only screen which is essentially has the same values as before.

Is there any way I can eliminate the duplicate entries (i.e. position, top, bottom, etc..) *except* padding-bottom under @media only screen?

TIA,

coson

Comment: You may want to search the reason why not work in the same way in Chrome not doing that `@media` declaration.

Comment: You should focus on the problem that something (which was not really specified here) fails to work on Chrome (in some way that was not disclosed), rather than finding a kludge that is supposed to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, CSS is cascading (hence the C). Just place the rules you wish to override inside the media query:

```
#data-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    #data-container {
        padding-bottom: 14px;

    }
}
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/MXFPG/)

If you inspect the element using Developer Tools, you'll see that `#data-container` inherits the styles of the CSS rule, but that `padding-bottom` is overwritten because the media query is applied. Here's the generated styles from Chrome, for example:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
#data-container {
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
#data-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```